# can autodesk forge viewer use offline data generated from model derivative api

Tags: autodesk-forge

Should I convert the saved 3D object by sending it to model derivative API every time I want to open it in the viewer, or I can save the generated data from model derivative API then run the viewer offline???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion into the viewer format is only needed once. After that you can load and view the converted output as many times as you want. Another conversion would only be needed if your model was modified.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the reply, I'm working on this walkthrough: https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview, and I see after the file uploaded it converted to .svf then send it to the viewer, but my question now is the model derivative API create another copy of the file, or just covert the original one and keep it in the same bucket??

Comment: When you ask the Model Derivative service to convert the source file (let's say a DWG), it will store the conversion output in its own storage under a unique `urn`, leaving the original file as is. From that point onward you can start loading the model (to be precise, the conversion output stored in the Model Derivative service) using its `urn` as many times as you want.