# What happens to uploaded CAD models after a conversion using the Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API?

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I need to maintain SVF2 versions of Inventor models for use with the Large Model Viewer as part of a web-based storefront application. These are fairly large Inventor assemblies, and I expect eventually we will convert a few hundred GB worth of Inventor data to SVF2. I am uploading the native models to a Forge bucket and executing a conversion job.

I am concerned about the amount of storage that will be required for this over time. Based on a reply to the answer on this post:

[can autodesk forge viewer use offline data generated from model derivative api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820531/can-autodesk-forge-viewer-use-offline-data-generated-from-model-derivative-api)

It appears that the SVF2 will have its own URN, so I may be able to safely delete the model. Will the entire manifest, including the database, continue to be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model Derivative service is not guaranteed to keep the translation outputs (i.e., SVF or SVF2) if the seed file is not available anymore, so I would suggest to keep the original files in your bucket.

Btw if you have a paid subscription, there is no limit to the amount of data you can keep in the Data Management service. Only the trial subscription is limited to 5GB.

Comment: Thanks! That makes complete sense.